# Knockout observable is displaying different information inside a function

Tags: knockout.js

I have a jQuery JSON function that pulls in a JSON file, maps it using Knockout mapping and then applies it to an observable array:

```
self.emails = ko.observableArray([]);
$.getJSON("emails.json", function(data) { 
    var emails = ko.mapping.fromJS(data);
    self.emails(emails());
});
```

The problem I'm having is that if I `alert` the self.emails() within the getJSON function, it displays all the objects inside, but if I `alert` the self.emails() outside of the getJSON function, it is empty.

I'm somewhat new to Knockout, but from my understanding, since I have them set as observables, they should hold the same value in and out of the function since they're applied to the `self` variable.

Am I doing something wrong or missing something here?

Comment: Are you sure the alert outside is firing after `getJSON` is done?

Comment: I put the alert at the very end of the function after all of my binding functions, so I figured it would be complete at that point, but even when I alert the observable outside the function all together it is still empty.

Comment: I believe you were right, I think it's just firing off the alert before the binding is processed.

Answer (score 1):

The reason the `alert` works inside of the callback of `$.getJSON()` is because that jQuery function is asynchronous and once it fires off the request to the server, then the next line of JavaScript is run and the results of mapping the emails is not complete and your `self.emails()` is empty.

The `$.getJSON()` syntax that you used:

```
$.getJSON("emails.json", function(data) { 
    var emails = ko.mapping.fromJS(data);
    self.emails(emails());
});
```

The `function(data) {` is the success callback of the `$.getJSON()` function, so it will execute when the AJAX request is done.

It would probably be clearer to use the promise/deferred syntax so that you can handle the AJAX request succeeding (`.done()`), failing (`.fail()`) and completing (`.always()`).

Here is an example of how you could do that with your code:

```
$.getJSON("emails.json")
    .done(function(data) {
        var emails = ko.mapping.fromJS(data);
        self.emails(emails());
        alert(self.emails());
    })
    .fail(function() {
        // Something bad happened

    })
    .always(function() {
        // No matter success or failure do something here
        // Typically I have used this to stop a busy wait icon or animation
        // so the user knows that the server-side processing is over

    });
```